# OpenCL not detecting AMD graphics card as a device

Tags: centos, xorg, drivers, graphics, amd-graphics

I am running CentOS 6. My OpenCL program is not detecting my graphics card as an option and is instead just running on my CPU. My program attempts to find and use the fastest device, but is only finding one option.

```
OpenCL Platform 0: AMD Accelerated Parallel Processing
OpenCL Device 0: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3612QM CPU @ 2.10GHz Gflops 16.808000
```

> Open CL Device: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3612QM CPU @ 2.10GHz

I have found multiple ways to inform myself that there is an issue. glxinfo gives me the following:

```
name of display: :0.0
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0.0".
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

lspci tells me that I have two VGA controllers, which from my understanding should never be the case:

> lspci -v | grep "VGA controller"

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Thames [Radeon HD 7550M/7570M/7650M] (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
```

(Obviously the one I want to use is the second one; the Radeon graphics card)

My Xorg.*.log(s) don't mention anything about AMD. It states the following, which I presume is significant (using intel as autoconfigured driver instead of amd?):

```
[    31.269] (==) Matched intel as autoconfigured driver 0
```

<s>With all of this said I am fairly certain that my issue has something to do with my drivers or lack thereof.</s> I will update this post as I attempt to resolve the issue but any help will probably make a difference!

Update 1: I know for fact that it's my drivers (or lack thereof), not my code because my exact code does find and run the code on the GPU.